# delete all subdirectories within a specificied directory in PHP?

Tags: php, while-loop, rmdir

How could I delete all subdirectories within a specified directory?

The directory is `c:/files/`

and I want to delete all subdirectories within their (example):

```
c:/files/something/something/something/

c:/files/another-something/
```

So in the end c:/files/ just remains (is empty and has no subdirectories).

`rmdir()` only removes the last directory in the given path...so I'm guessing i'd have to loop? :/

All help appreciated.

(PS: the subdirectories don't contain any files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [PHP manual entry for rmdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php):

```
 function rrmdir($dir) { 
   if (is_dir($dir)) { 
     $objects = scandir($dir); 
     foreach ($objects as $object) { 
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object); 
       } 
     } 
     reset($objects); 
     rmdir($dir); 
   } 
 }
```

This solves the problem using recursion.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `RMDIR /S`

For example, the following command will remove directory `C:\blah` and all subdirectories and files contained therein. No prompt will be displayed.

`RMDIR c:\blah /s /q`